# Javascript load on page

Tags: javascript, html, css, pageload

I want that the title and subtitle shows up when the page loads. I tried several times to let it work but it won't.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){                  

 jQuery('.element').bind('mouseover', function() {
    jQuery(this).find('img').stop().each(function() {
      jQuery(this).animate({
        'opacity': 1
      }, 200);
    });
 });

  jQuery('.element').bind('mouseout', function() {
   jQuery(this).find('img').stop().each(function() {
      jQuery(this).animate({
        'opacity': 0.4
      }, 200);
    });
 });


  jQuery('.element').on('pageload', function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.title').stop().each(function() {
      jQuery(this).animate({
        'margin-left': 35,
         'opacity': 1
      }, 250);
    });
    jQuery(thi2s).find('.subtitle').stop().each(function() {
      jQuery(this).animate({
         'opacity': 1
      }, 0);
      jQuery(this).delay(150).animate({
        'margin-left': 35
      }, 250);
    });
  });
```

});

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: pageload? Are you using jQuery mobile?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you running `pageload` was deprecated in 1.4.

Comment: I dont know. Where can I check that?

Comment: I'm not the best in javascript. I dont know of pageload is right.

Comment: i use it for my website

Comment: If you found an answer to your question, please enter it as a answer below and mark it as accepted, or delete the question. We don't add "solved" to titles here.

Comment: What was the solution? I still see obvious errors in your code....

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do, but at a first glance, I noticed this bug:

```
jQuery(thi2s).find('.subtitle').stop().each(function() {
    // code
}
```

Obviously, the extraneous '2' should not be there, but I'm not sure if this small fix will create the intended behavior you are looking for.

Here's an example of how you should structure your code. You shouldn't really use the `.bind()` function for your events or reference elements using `jQuery('.element')`. Additionally the excessive use of `this` is unnecessary and complicates your code.

Consider this basic example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("div").hover(
    function () {
        $("h2").animate({
            left: 50,
            opacity: 1
        }, 500);
    }, function () {
        $("h2").animate({
            left: 50,
            opacity: 0.2
        }, 500);
    });

});
```

Check out [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92d5d79b/).

Hope this helps!